# how to insert a mysql mediumtext field with perl

Tags: mysql, perl

I am new to perl,and today I encounted a problem. I want to fetch a url page content then save it to  mysql.

here is mysql table strutcture:

```
table:webpage
id INT(11)
url VARCHAR(300)
html mediumtext
```

below is my perl code

```
use DBI;
use LWP::Simple;
use Encode;
$url="http://search.cpan.org/~rfoley/File-Data-1.15/lib/File/Data.pm";
$content = get($url);
my $dbh = DBI->connect( 'DBI:mysql:mytest', 'root', '123' );
$dbh->begin_work();
$dbh->do("INSERT INTO webpage (id, url,html) VALUES (1,$url,$content)");
$dbh->commit();
$dbh->disconnect();
```

then the output as follow

```
DBD::mysql::db do failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version 
for the right syntax to use  near ':
//search.cpan.org/~rfoley/File-Data-1.15/lib/File/Data.pm,<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC'
at line 1 at E:/program_data/eclipse_j2ee_workspace/pdemo/db.pl line 9.
```

is anyone can help me .thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need, at a minimum, to quote the string values in your query. Something like:

```
$dbh->do("INSERT INTO webpage (id, url,html) VALUES (1,'$url','$content')");
```

But this is not safe at all, `$content` in particular could contain quotes or other symbols that would at best break your query, at worst kill your database (read about SQL Injection).

So you should consider using [placeholders and bind values](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI-1.616/DBI.pm#Placeholders_and_Bind_Values) to avoid those pitfalls.

Comment: thanks Mat,but it still not work. I use $dbh->do("INSERT INTO webpage (id, url,html) VALUES (1,'$url','$content')")  instead of the original.I think i should take a look at ' placeholders and bind values' model.

Comment: "still not work" doesn't provide any information about what is not working exactly, and how it's failing.

Comment: the output error message is follow: 'DBD::mysql::db do failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'btn btn_h'" onmouseout="this.className='btn'"></span></form><div id="mCon"><span' '    <br>thanks all the same, i have not use the 'placeholders and bind values' model,and it is better to do it now.

Comment: Then you should be using placeholders and bind values as I posted. Anything else, when you don't control the input, is dangerous. (Except properly escaping the input, but binds can have other benefits depending on the database system itself.)

Answer (score 0):

Quote your string before insert :

```
$content = $dbh->quote($content);
```

Answer (score 0):

Better, use placeholders

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO webpage (id, url,html) VALUES (1,?,?)');
$sth->execute($url,$content);
```